# Building for iOS Simulator but linking object file built for iOS error

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

**I have a macbook Air M1 and i cloned my project and tried to run that then got this, how could i fix this?**

Showing Recent Issues
In /Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/apps/iOS/newC/xxxxxxxx_xxxxxx/xxxx.xxxxxxx.Mobile.iOS/x_xxxxxxxxxx/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFURL.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file

'/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/apps/iOS/newC/xxxxxxxx_xxxxxx/xxxx.xxxxxxx.Mobile.iOS/x_xxxxxxxxxx_Mcash/Bolts.framework/Bolts' for architecture arm64

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem myself:

```
post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
      end
  end
```

Based on [this page](https://www.dynamsoft.com/barcode-reader/docs/mobile/programming/objectivec-swift/faq/arm64-simulator-error.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).